# facebook like box for group page

Tags: html, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to create a likebox for a group page on facebook (https://www.facebook.com/groups/lrwg1/) and not having much success. I'm not sure if https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ is supposed to display a demo of what the box will look like on it's right hand side (it seems to in guides online) but mine remains blank when I put the URL in. I've tried all the types of code but none work. I do seem to get a white box but that is as far as I get. I've looked at a fair few tutorials online but apologies if this is a simple issue.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: You can't like a group!

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan is right, trying with the provided URL gives the following (obvious) error message: The `href` parameter must reference a valid Facebook page, but "https://www.facebook.com/groups/lrwg1/" is not a valid Facebook page.

Comment: is there anyway to get a simular feature from facebook for a group?